# Calculating the probability of various sets

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Let $x∈[0,1]$. $\forall a≤b\in[0,1]$ we denote the probability that $x\in[a,b]$
> as $P([a,b])$.
>
> Assume $P([a,b]) = P((a,b]) = P((a,b)) = P([a,b)) = b - a$.
>
> We define the following events:
>
> $$A_{i} = \left[\frac{1}{i},1\right] \forall i\in\mathbb{N}$$
>
> $$B_{n} = {\displaystyle \bigcup _{i=n}^{∞}A_{i}}$$
>
> $$C_{n} = {\displaystyle \bigcap _{i=n}^{∞}A_{i}}$$
>
> $$D = {\displaystyle \bigcap _{n=1}^{∞}B_{n}}$$
>
> $$E = {\displaystyle \bigcup _{n=1}^{∞}C_{n}}$$
>
> Find $P(A_{i}),P(B_{n}),P(C_{n}),P(D),P(E)$.

We only had one lecture so far in our probability course, and we haven't really seen how to solve something like this. It seems that the professor wants us to figure the solution on our own, but as we've concentrated purely on basic definitions and combinatorics I find myself having trouble proving this question formally.

**My attempt**

Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 0$, then $\forall i,n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have :

\begin{align}&P(A_{i})= P(\left[\frac{1}{i},1\right]) \\&\boxed{P(A_{i})= 1 - \frac{1}{i}}\\
&P(B_{n}) =P(\ A_{n}∪A_{n+1}∪A_{n+2}∪...\ )\\&=P(\ \left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]∪\left[\frac{1}{n+1},1\right]∪\left[\frac{1}{n+2},1\right]∪\left[\frac{1}{n+3},1\right]...\ )\\&=P(\ \left(0,1\right]) \\&= 1 - 0 \\&\boxed{P(B_{n})= 1} 
\\&P(C_{n\ })=P(A_{n}∩A_{n+1}∩A_{n+2}∩...\ )\\&=P(\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right]∩\left[\frac{1}{n+1},1\right]∩\left[\frac{1}{n+2},1\right]∩\left[\frac{1}{n+3},1\right]...\ )\\&=P(\ \left[\frac{1}{n},1\right] )\\&\boxed{P(C_{n\ })= 1 - \frac{1}{n}}\\  
&P(D)=P(B_{1}∩B_{2}∩B_{3}∩...\ )\\&=P(\left(A_{1}∪A_{2}∪A_{3}∪...\right)∩\left(A_{2}∪A_{3}∪A_{4}...\right))\\&=P(A_{\lim_{n\to\infty}n}) \\&=\left(0,1\right] \\&\boxed{P(D)= 1}\\  
&P(E)=P(C_{1}∪C_{2}∪C_{3}∪...\ )\\&=P(\left(A_{1}∩A_{2}∩A_{3}∩...\right)∪\left(A_{2}∩A_{3}∩A_{4}...\right))\\&=P(A_{\lim_{n\to\infty}n}\ ∪A_{\lim_{n\to\infty}n}∪...)\\&=P(\left(0,1\right])\\&\boxed{P(E)=\ 1}\\ \end{align}

I feel like I'm just writing nonsense... we've learned the inclusion-exclusion formula which seems to fit perfectly for these calculations but I don't feel comfortable using it yet.. I'm looking to learn how do I solve these type of questions because I just feel lost. :(

Comment: Your solutions are correct I believe but there is an easier way to see this. Note that $A_{n}\subset A_{n+1}$ that is these are increasing sets. If we consider $\cup_{i=n}^{\infty}A_i$ then since $A_n$ contains all the first n-1 sets then this is equivalent to $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i=(0,1]$. for the second consider the fact that $\cap_{i=n}^{\infty}A_i=A_n$ by the same fact that these are increasing sets. This should help you solve for the rest.

Comment: This is one of those problems where it helps to get into the mind of the problem composer.  You haven't been studying probability theory.  Therefore, the point of the problem is not to compute the requested probabilities, but rather to identify for each question, the exact nature of the corresponding set.  Once you do that, then you can rely on intuition to complete the problem.  For example: $$C_n = \left\{\left[\frac{1}{n},1\right] \cap \left[\frac{1}{n+1},1\right] \cap \left[\frac{1}{n+2},1\right] \cap \cdots\right\} = \{1\},$$ so $C_n$ only has 1 element in it.  Therefore, $p(C_n) = 0.$

Comment: Re previous comment, it isn't obvious, but the conclusion comes from the added premise that $p( ~[a,b] ~) = p( ~(a,b) ~).$  This is actually a weak part of the instructor's problem, because, *without training*, you are supposed to infer from this premise that the probability that $x$ equals a specific element in $[0,1]$ is $(0)$.